# Usercontrol different controls properties access

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

i created my first WPF MVVM pattern solution. I created a UserControl and I would like to reuse this control in my MainWindow, because style is the same only differents between this both controls are the datasource. First Control uses ObervableCollection index 0 and second UserControl uses from the same OberservableCollection index 1. The observablecollection is in my Mainviewmodel and the binding works well, if I make the binding inside of my UserControl.

Dont want to bind inside of the UserControl to my model like this:

**UserControl:**

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="PersonModel.FirstName"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="PersonModel.FirstName"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

I would like to bind each nested control of my Usercontrol in my MainWindow.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<desktop:UserControl1 Textblock1.Text="{Binding PersonModel.FirstName} TextBlock2.Text="{Binding PersonModel.LastName}"></desktop:UserControl1>
```

Comment: Similar question and some answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491951/xaml-access-to-controls-inside-user-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to expose anything *bindable* as `UserControl` dependency properties, here is `CustomText` one:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public string CustomText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CustomTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomTextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CustomText", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata());

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

In xaml you bind to it:

```
<UserControl ... >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomText}"  />
</UserControl>
```

And the usage will be:

```
<local:UserControl1 CustomText="{Binding SomeProperty" />
```

Another approach is to use callback of dependency property, this way you can change many things in code behind of `UserControl`, e.g. start animation.

I don't know if there is a way to expose complete child control of `UserControl`, but maybe you don't need that (rather create few dedicated dependency properties to change specific property of specific control).

---

One more possibility is to give `UserControl` a name and use it in code behind of window. In such case you can expose `UserControl` controls by giving them names (`x:Name`) and using properties:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public TextBlock TextBlock => textBlock; // textBlock is x:Name
    ...
}
```

Now you can [bind in code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2938656/1997232) to e.g. `userControl1.TextBlock.Visibility` (where `userControl1` is an `x:Name` of `<local:UserControl1 />`).